# Akka Streams: a Flow over a running process

Tags: stream, akka

How do you make a Flow over a process? Lets say I have a process that gets input via stdin and sends output via stdout. I want to have a Flow over it. So the Flow will initially startup the process, control its input and output stream and then act as a Map, mapping the input to output by feeding it to the process? And ultimately terminating the process when the stream ends. Also how would back-pressure control work in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic [Flow that is "coupled"](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stages-overview.html#flow-fromsinkandsourcecoupled) so that it terminates due to an interrupt from either input or output (sink/source). For simplicity I've assumed the case where there is no stdin, but you could adapt this to add a `Sink` that isn't ignored and [pipes input into the process](http://pipes%20input%20into%20the%20process):

```
// capture stdout from the "ls" command
val runCmd: Source[Message, NotUsed] = {
    Source.fromIterator[Message](() => Process("ls").lineStream.toIterator.map(line => TextMessage.Strict(line)))
  }

// create flow for emitting stdout source to client
val messageStdout: Flow[Any, Message, NotUsed] = Flow
    .fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(Sink.ignore, runCmd)
```

As for backpressure, notice above my code example is a blocking `map` operation (one `line` at a time). As the rate of processing grows, you can develop an asynchronous solution, and one that has a maximum parallelism obeying backpressure as defined by [mapasync](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stages-overview.html#mapasync).